# Specflow generate single file

Tags: c#, specflow

I've made something that allows you to run a specflow feature file at runtime.  At the moment, it's fairly nasty - it actually generates the code and compile it. I'd like to get to the point where that's not necessary one day - however the worst bit is that the specflow generator, as far as I can tell, will only work if the file is part of a project - so I have to generate a project - even though I can quite happily compile a C# program on it's lonesome.

So - the question - is there any way, using the specflow tools or libraries - of taking a single .feature file and turning it into a feature.cs file, without any other files (especially a .csproj) being involved?

Comment: Try checking out the code and using the results of the Generator project.https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/tree/master/Generator

Comment: won't you need a (some) cs file(s) containing the steps as well (and step argument transformations etc) in order to populate the feature.cs file with the correctly mapped methods?

Comment: It might also be worth noting that creating projects and compiling them and then running specflow from the command line is how some of the integration tests inside the specflow project are used to test specflow itself.

Comment: another thought is that you might be able to use scriptcs to run the files without a csproj

Comment: the cs doesn't map the methods - it puts the strings in.  I've actually thought of going the other way and not actually generating code at all, but dynamically calling all the methods - that would mean I'd have to do the specflow parsing myself - including all the table and outline handling - possible, but annoying.    The main problem with creating the project, which is working at the moment is the speed - it's quite slow to go through a full write, generate, compile, run nunit cycle.

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? To be able to open a feature file and run the tests in a stand alone application? then edit the feature file and run it again? What about when you introduce a new step? What code will run when this happens?

Comment: We have BA's who write tests and developers who write steps.  Most tests can be achieved with existing tests.  I'm writing (I've written - it works actually, just much slower than it should be) - a web site where a BA can just log in, drag steps in, fill out details, and click run or save - and then make "playlists" to run sets of tests - all without going near anything "techie".  If they want new steps, they have to ask for one from a developer, who writes it and turns it over.